# Is the statement $|a − b| \le \gcd(a, b)$ true?

Tags: number-theory

Is the statement $|a − b| \le \gcd(a, b)$ true?

How to prove the statement?

I've tried to use the FTA but I'm stuck there.

Comment: Lets try $a=2$ and $b=10.$

Answer (score 3):

If $a=b$, then yes, otherwise the opposite $|a-b|\ge \gcd(a,b)$ is true, because $\gcd(a,b)|a-b$.

Comment: What if $a=b=2$?

Comment: Good point, I should insist $a\not = b$.

Comment: Should I prove gcd(a,b)|a-b for this question?

Comment: That's straightforward, as $\gcd(a,b)$ divides both $a$ and $b$ by definition.